# Programmatically get certificate from PKCS12 with nokeys

Tags: openssl, libssl

I am trying to do the equivalent of this openssl command programmatically, which works fine:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in filename.p12 -nokeys -out output.crt
```

However, when I try this:

```
    if (PKCS12_parse(p12, "password", &pkey, &x509_cert, nullptr) == 0) {
        throw MyException("PKCS12_parse failed");
    }
```

pkey and x509_cert are returned as null and no exception is thrown.

p12 was created with "nokeys":

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -nokeys -in input.crt -out filename.p12
```